# Why is my computer misinterpreting the behavior of the scroll wheel?

Tags: mouse, scrolling

Short version: When I scroll up or down, it usually scrolls the way it should, but intermittently it scrolls the other way.  Why?

I'm using a wireless mouse on my laptop (Lenovo, Windows 7).  When I scroll the wheel downwards, the window is fairly likely to scroll downwards, but not infrequently it scrolls upwards instead.  When I scroll up, the same issue happens.  (Just did a quick test of about 50 attempts and had a 36% failure rate, where the window scrolled the opposite direction of the wheel.)

At the moment, I'm using a typical Microsoft wireless mouse, but I've had the same issue on this computer with other similar mice I've tried.

I'd understand if it were a hardware problem with the mouse's scroll wheel, but since this occurs with other mice, it seems unlikely to be the case.

What else could it be?  Why is my computer misunderstanding the scroll wheel?

Comment: have you tried wired mouse? might be wireless-specific glitch or manufacturer bug

Comment: are you tech savvy enough to load a linux live cd or usb drive?  That would tell you if it is your hardware, or windows.

Comment: @Keltari, that sounds like it's beyond what I'm comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

"That computer" , it does not happen on others regularly, and it likely is not the mouse when other mices do the same thing on the same computer. This makes it more likely that it is dueling softwares. 
 More than one input device softwares can hook into the mouse control, could be you have 2 softwares running that are hooked in, that includes trackpads,touchpad software also.  Does it do it in safe modes?

Because you have applied more than one mouse item on that computer, you may have also installed more software than one mouse needed. Because the mouse control software for windows links the port data into the system,  much the same way as any other input device software, it would be easy for the software to remain operational, even when that particular input device is no longer present.

The simplest first thing to do would be to look in your Programs and Features listings in the control pannel, and see if there is software that you can uninstall, because it is no longer needed.  With all 3rd party input device software removed, generally there will still be the MS default driver items left, compatable with most simple mices, and the simplest operations will still function.

other notes: While the optical sencor and comparitor routines (used for the wheel) could be prone to reversal when dirty or flawed circuitry, it is unlikely to happen in all your mices at once, and likely to bounce around during any single movement of it, not reverse for the whole move.

There are input devices that have full hardware ID, and the software for those devices will not be functioning without the device present. Depends on the complexity of the device and software, and methods used for programming. Much of the simple software though is more cross compatable between them, and could create a conflict.